# Add values to existing cookie in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am facing the following task:

As the user navigates the site logs onto the website, write the
following information

Current Date
 Current Time
 Name of up to 5 Products the user viewed or Ordered during the visit
As I don't really have a product list site, I was going to do on the order screen. When user inputs the quantity to order I have a TextChanged event. So I can get details of a single product with the required information, but I am not sure how to keep adding to it?

This is what I am doing atm:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
    {
     //   string pName1 =      GridView1.DataKeys[test].Values["ProductName"].ToString();
        testCookie.Values.Add("CurrentDate", currentDate);
        testCookie.Values.Add("CurrentTime", currentTime);
        testCookie.Values.Add("ProductName", pName);
        Label lblPartStatus = ((Label)row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label8"));
        double testprice = Convert.ToDouble(lblPartStatus.Text);
        grandTotal = grandTotal + testprice;
    }
```

And also, how do I limit/check the amount of products that have been saved in the cookie and replace the oldest one with a newer ones?

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: these values will be overriden and you will get last record in cookie

Comment: So do I need to create a new key for each entry, ie. have ProductName1 to ProductName5 to keep all of them?

Comment: Error 7 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>' when trying to read session

Comment: Sorry, my bad... its on string date = entry["CurrentDate" + i].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend to create `Dictionary` object and add key value pair to it then store dictionary into `Session`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
int i = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
    {
        dic.Add("CurrentDate" + i, currentDate);
        dic.Add("CurrentTime" + i, currentTime);
        dic.Add("ProductName" + i, pName);
        i++;
        // your code
    }

Session["dic"] = dic;
```

For retrieving those values.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["dic"];
int i = 0;
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dic)
{
      string date = entry.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I am getting those two errors:

    Error 8 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Error 9 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' to 'string' 

I changed the dictionary to be Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>(); as all data is in a string format.

Comment: How you initialized dictionary? Add that coe

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Cookie: HttpCookie testCookie = new HttpCookie("testCookie");

Comment: How are you adding elements in for loop?

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
         //   string pName1 = GridView1.DataKeys[test].Values["ProductName"].ToString();
            dic.Add("CurrentDate", currentDate);
            dic.Add("CurrentTime", currentTime);
            dic.Add("ProductName", pName);
            Label lblPartStatus = ((Label)row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label8"));
            double testprice = Convert.ToDouble(lblPartStatus.Text);
            grandTotal = grandTotal + testprice;
        }

Comment: Oh, my mistake, you can store only string into cookie :(

Comment: I'll try using session, thanks. How can I read values from session?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94075/discussion-between-user3468334-and-imad).